# Get one-to-one relationship objects with JOIN query with myBatis

Tags: java, mybatis, one-to-one, spring-mybatis

I try to use MyBatis to get from database object, which have another object as field. Like this:

```
public class Worker {
  private int id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  private Bank bank;   
}

public class Bank  {
  private int id;
  private String name;
}
```

As can be seen,  here should be one-to-one relationship.
At the moment I found only two solutions:

1) Add @Result annotation to WorkerMapper with reference to the bank sql, like this:

```
public interface WorkerMapper {
  @Results({
    @Result(column = "id",          property = "id"),
    @Result(column = "first_name",  property = "firstName"),
    @Result(column = "last_name",   property = "lastName"),
    @Result(property="bank", javaType=Bank.class, column="id", many=@Many(select="getBank"))
  })
  @Select("worker select")
  Worker get(int id);

  @Select("bank select")
  Bank getBank(int id);
)
```

But, if I understand correctly, if I do this, me need execute two queries^ for bank and for workers. Which is not very good for the BD

2) I can write sql query with "inner join", create some "RowAdapter" class, which contains all query fields. After I get it from the database, I will parse on the my necessary objects.
This solution is better than two queries, but it is necessary to write a lot of code.

Is there a more elegant solution to get two objects with one sql query with "inner join" in MyBatis (desirable use annotation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that using `@Many` involve that  `Worker` class has `Collection<Bank>` property. In you case, you must use `@One`.

Just quoting [API documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html):

> `@One`: A mapping to a single property value of a complex type.
>   Attributes: select, which is the fully qualified name of a mapped
>   statement (i.e. mapper method) that can load an instance of the
>   appropriate type,

The potential interest of multiple queries is `lazyLoading` to get the Bank date just in time.

> fetchType, which supersedes the global configuration parameter
>   lazyLoadingEnabled for this mapping.

It actually depends on your requirement.

- If this is limited to select worker by id then select bank by id,
  there is not much difference between 2 simple queries and a single
  JOIN query.
- If you select all workers (let say 1 million), then 1 million
  select-bank could be issued. A JOIN query could be preferable if lazy
  loading is not an option.

Anyway,

> NOTE You will notice that join mapping is not supported via the
>   Annotations API. This is due to the limitation in Java Annotations
>   that does not allow for circular references.

Then defining result map in XML is required for JOIN query. With auto-mapping, following should be almost enough:

```
<resultMap id ="workerResultMap" type="Worker">
  <association property="bank" resultMap="bankResultMap"/>
</resultMap>
<resultMap id ="bankResultMap" type="Bank">
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. @Many - this is misspelling, but still nice that you have considered it. You confirmed my worst fears, thank you for this)